# CWTBG0019E: Exception information: with name "SQL Execute Statement"

Tags: ibm-bpm

CWTBG0019E: Unexpected exception during execution. Exception information: 'com.lombardisoftware.component.common.workflow.WorkflowProcessItemException: An exception occurred in activity "Execute" of "Integration Service" with name "SQL Execute Statement". Task instance id "Task.1069". Details: "sql".'.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.